# SQL Server - OPENXML for XML within XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xslt

I have an issue where I am reading data from an XML and one of the columns is an another XML.  When I adjust the data type to varchar(max) or nvarchar(max)  I get  Null and when using XML data type I get "Element-centric mapping must be used with OPENXML when one of the columns is of type XML."

The column that contains the raw XML is raw_xml.

My goal would be to save the XML as another table with attributes of the parent XML, but I am failing in even reading it.

```
declare @xml XML

SELECT @xml=CAST(REPLACE(y, 'UTF-16','UTF-8') as XML)
FROM OPENROWSET( BULK 'D:\myxml.xml', SINGLE_CLOB) x(y)

DECLARE @hdoc int
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, @xml

Select * 
from OPENXML (@hdoc, '/LoanApplications/LoanApplication/LoanApplicationStates/LoanApplicationState/Customers/Customer/Reports/Report',1)
WITH(
    active varchar(255),
    valid varchar(255),
    bureau varchar(255),
    report_date datetime,
    score varchar(255),
    --raw_xml varchar(255),
    raw_xml [xml] ,
    create_date datetime,
    update_date datetime,
    updated_by varchar(255),
    deal_detail_id bigint,
    bundle_id bigint
    )

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hdoc
```

Sample XML, The data stored in xml_raw doesnt look like XML format, but not sure if that because of the formatting or not.

```
       <Reports>
          <Report active="True" valid="True" bureau="EX" report_date="2016-03-27T19:06:32.3470000" score="111" raw_xml="&lt;Response Score=&quot;111&quot;" create_date="2016-03-27T19:06:32.4430000" update_date="2016-03-27T19:06:32.4430000" updated_by="System [No User Available]" deal_detail_id="123" bundle_id="5656" />
        </Reports>
```

Comment: The usage of `FOR OPENXML` in combination with the two SPs tp prepare and remove are outdated and should not be used any more. If you don't show the content of your XML (reduced to the point!) we cannot help you.

Comment: Here is a sample of the raw XML, under the reports node.

Comment: please use the edit option of your question to put the XML into the question. There you mark it and declare it as "code" with strg+k, otherwise XML get's problems due to the markups...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx for the example...

If you execute this

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
' <Reports>
    <Report active="True" valid="True" bureau="EX" report_date="2016-03-27T19:06:32.3470000" score="111" raw_xml="&lt;Response Score=&quot;111&quot;" create_date="2016-03-27T19:06:32.4430000" update_date="2016-03-27T19:06:32.4430000" updated_by="System [No User Available]" deal_detail_id="123" bundle_id="5656" />
</Reports>';

SELECT @xml.value('(/Reports/Report/@raw_xml)[1]','varchar(max)');
```

You get this

```
<Response Score="111"
```

The problem is, that your attribut "raw_xml" seems to be the beginning of XML, but it is not complete... You'll not be able to cast this to XML...

Did you manipulate the XML in order to reduce it for an example, or is this your "real data"? If it's real, your might be in trouble...

#### UPDATE

Just to show you how to get the data without `FOR OPENXML`

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
' <Reports>
    <Report active="True" valid="True" bureau="EX" report_date="2016-03-27T19:06:32.3470000" score="111" raw_xml="&lt;Response Score=&quot;111&quot;" create_date="2016-03-27T19:06:32.4430000" update_date="2016-03-27T19:06:32.4430000" updated_by="System [No User Available]" deal_detail_id="123" bundle_id="5656" />
</Reports>';

SELECT R.value('@active','bit') AS active
      ,R.value('@valid','bit') AS valid
      ,R.value('@bureau','varchar(max)') AS bureau
      ,R.value('@report_date ','datetime') AS report_date 
      ,R.value('@score ','int') AS score 
      ,R.value('@raw_xml ','varchar(max)') AS raw_xml 
      ,R.value('@create_date ','datetime') AS create_date 
      ,R.value('@update_date ','datetime') AS update_date 
      ,R.value('@updated_by ','varchar(max)') AS updated_by 
      ,R.value('@deal_detail_id ','bigint') AS deal_detail_id 
      ,R.value('@bundle_id ','bigint') AS bundle_id 
FROM @xml.nodes('/Reports/Report') AS A(R);
```

Comment: Its a manipulated sample, but the raw_xml doesn't really look like an XML structure.  The other issue is it is massive, I dont think it will fit in a varchar(max).

Comment: @Omid, it *actually does* look like XML, but it is encoded, because you are packing XML into XML. The starting `&lt;` codes for "less than" and is the opening angle, the `&qout;` stands for a qout and so on. Try my query against your real data. And try to this: `CAST(R.value('@raw_xml ','varchar(max)') AS XML)`

Comment: That looks to have done the trick, I am now about to view the XML in the column and will try to parse it.  Thank you so much for getting past my brain fart!

Comment: @Omid, I'm glad to read this. And if you get into troubles with the XML - just start a new question. Welcome on SO! If you place a link here, I'll get an alert and jump there SOreadytohelp :-)